# someone has greater depths to them

Tags: expressions

Does the phrase "someone has greater depths to them" mean that someone has a better personality than you think?

Thank you

Comment: Help us help you. Where did you come across the phrase? What resources did you consult? Mind editing your post and providing some details?

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that "***greater depths***" necessarily infers a *better* personality so much as a *more complex* personality than you realized.

"When a person is described as having "**depth**", it is in reference to hidden multiple layers and qualities of the person's character, intellect or personality.

> If you say that someone or something has **depth**, you mean that they have serious and interesting qualities which are not immediately obvious and which you have to think about carefully before you can fully understand them. *"We felt at home with her and were impressed with the **depth** of her knowledge..."*
>   [[ReversoDictionary.com]](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/he%20has%20depth%20of%20character)

A common English idiom which relates to this is the saying:

> "Still waters run **deep**."

...which means that the speaker is describing a quiet person as someone with more **depth**.

Also illuminating is the antonym, *shallow*, (which is not a compliment.)

For further learning on the nuances of ***"depth of character"***, see
[this fun poem called ***"Depth of Character,"*** written by Donald Mass.](http://writerunboxed.com/2011/02/02/depth-of-character/)
[[WriterUnboxed.com Blog]](http://writerunboxed.com/2011/02/02/depth-of-character/)